# Question about application of double integrals to find out volume of solid cone!

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

A solid cone is obtained by connecting every point of a plane region S with a vertex not in the plane of S. Let A denote the area of S, and let h denote the altitude of the cone.

Prove that the cross-sectional area cut by a plane parallel to the base and at a distance t from the vertex is A(t/h)^2, 0

To find out cross-sectional area, I have to integrate the function with respect to x.

However, since this can be any solid cone, How can I define the function?

Answer (score 1):

We can see that the cross-sectional figure is obtained by an homothety transformation of the base S with respecto to the vertex, and where the factor of the transformacion is the value k=t/h. So may be important to make the following question: How the area of a plane region change when we apply a homothety?
The answer to this question can be deduced by using some properties of the integral, we shall concluide that the area of the new figure is the K^2*A, where A is the area of the initial figure and k is the factor of the homothety. With this in mind we can easy deduce that the cross-sectional area in question is (t/h)^2*A.